# Network call inside a Service for a widget

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a question related to Android Widget (those on the Home Screen)
I'm trying to create a widget that will update its content on a periodic time.

I use a Service which is called to do that.
When I tried to make a basic network call (GET) inside this service, I'm having NetworkOnMainThread exception.

I know what this exception is but I thought Services in Android were in a separate Thread. So I just mistaken ...

So, in order to do that, I did an AsyncTask but I'm not satisfied of my code, I just think what I made is not a good usage.
Call anyone tell me if my thought is right ?

Here is the content of my Service :

```
public class ServiceUpdate extends Service
{
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        String res = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // Getting something from the WWW
            res = Network.getStringFromWS("http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // Substring for test
            res = res.substring(0, 100);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, res);

            ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TimeWidgetProvider.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            manager.updateAppWidget(thiswidget, remoteViews);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }.execute();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}
```

}

Thank you all for your point of view !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `AsyncTask` in your service, extend [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it is simpler.

Also, it'll be better to have some sort of caching mechanism. First you update the cache, second you update widget with data from cache. This way your widget will be completely autonomous. You might use content provider for that.

One more note. When using simple service, don't forget to stop it. In your case you have to call `stopSelf` in `onPostExecute`. You don't have to explicitly stop an `IntentService`